# How to wire a condensate pump safety switch?

Tags: hvac

So, just got back from vacation to find much of my basement covered with a decent amount of water. Discovered my condensate pump stopped working (worn float) and overflowed for probably most of the week.

The pump has a safety overflow cut-off switch but it was never set up and so I finally did that (or tried at least) once I replaced the float and cleaned up the mess. Problem is the shut off does not appear to function. The pump is a Diversitech CP-22 with three terminals (com, run and alarm). I separated 2 yellow wires connecting the t-stat and outdoor unit and connected the t-stat wire to the provided lead wire to the com terminal at the pump and then connected the second lead wire from the run terminal at the pump to the yellow wire from the outdoor unit. Turned everything back on and all appears to work fine except the cut-off feature. T-stat calls for cool, condenser kicks on outside and house cools normally to set temp. The pump functions fine when full but when I tried to test the overflow feature by manually filling it with water faster than it could pump it out, the pump just overflowed and never shut the system off although the red alarm LED was lit up.

What did I do wrong here or could this be a faulty switch? The pump is at least 6 years old.

Comment: It sounds like the safety switch function is between "con" and "alarm" not "con" and "run"

Comment: I have been in a few newer houses that use these things - they always seemed like a problem waiting to happen which would have been easily avoided at design time by putting a drain in the correct location...?

Comment: I agree the pumps do fail and floats stick a drain is the best way. After several failures in my last home I opened up the walls and added a drain. Never had another problem after that.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer? You'll get an upvote from me -- my theory was wrong *chuckles*

Answer (score 3):

The correct wiring scheme for shutting down the AC completely is to break the 24v red wire (low voltage) coming from the t-stat bundle and then wire it in to the (COM) terminal of the pump. Then attach the second lead to the (RUN) terminal at the pump to the second red wire going to the control board/transformer.  The (ALARM) terminal of the pump is intended to attach an audible alarm device that would be tied into the red low voltage t-stat wire. The previous wiring scheme will also work but only shuts down the outside unit's compressor, however the fan will continue to run.

Answer (score -2):

I would agree with the 1st comment on running the yellow wire to Con and Alarm.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We prefer answers to stand on their own, as comments often get edited or deleted. Would you edit your answer to include all the information? Thanks!